# Struts2 tag If using IteratorStatus

Tags: struts2, tags, iterator

I am starting with Struts2 and I need help  to solve an issue on my IF tag.

This my code

```
public class InventoryRow {
    private String title;
    private int[] qty = new int[5];
    private boolean[] warningFlag = new boolean[5];
}
```

In Action class I have this property:

```
private List<InventoryRow> parts = new ArrayList<InventoryRow>();
```

In my JSP, I would like to apply different style according with qty[] value or warningFlag[] value.

```
<s:iterator value="parts" var="product">  
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="title" /></td>
        <s:iterator value="qty" var="val" status="idStatus">  
            <td class="qty <s:if test="#val==-99"> none</s:if>
                   <s:elseif test="#warningdFlag[%{#idStatus.index}] == true"> warning</s:elseif>
                           " >
                <s:property />
            </td>     
        </s:iterator> 
   </tr> 
</s:iterator>
```

The first test (equal -99) works. But not the second one (using warningFlag)

Thanks in advance for your help and your advertisement.

Mickael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` before `warningFlag` is not needed and you have typo `warningdFlag` should be `warningFlag`.

```
<s:iterator value="parts">  
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="title" /></td>
        <s:iterator value="qty" var="val" status="idStatus">  
            <td class="qty <s:if test="#val==-99"> none</s:if>
                   <s:elseif test="warningFlag[#idStatus.index]"> warning</s:elseif>" >
                <s:property />
            </td>     
        </s:iterator> 
   </tr> 
</s:iterator>
```

The `%{...}` notation on getting status index inside `test` attribute is not needed because `test` takes expression as a value.

Also see this link: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/ognl.html.

Comment: Hi Aleksandr,   I applyed your advise but I have the same result.

Comment: @OurtaauMickael: You need to remove `%{...}` from elseif as well. Missed that in the first time. See an update.

Comment: It works. thank you. I did not found into strut documentation any information about the attribut "test" in IF tag. When do I put%{}? what does means the #?. I used JSTL TAG 6 years ago but I forgot all my knowledge about this. If you have a tuto or a link for my...

Comment: @OurtaauMickael: Updated my answer. Do not forget accept/upvote answers.

Comment: @OurtaauMickael Why don't you accept this answer as correct answer? or else comment if your need more help!!!

Comment: Sorry I had to stop my project. Now, I think I qccept the answer if not let me kno how to do it.